Detect moving persons by analyzing pair of images
Consider a case where you want to detect moving persons. No animals exist at the place.
The illumination at the place may vary a lot.
You don't have to detect immobile humans.
A camera produces a stream of photos, for instance two images per second.
Would it be possible to send two consecutive images to a neural network for classification?
A moving person would cause a lot of pixels to change when you compare the first
image with the second image.
Would it be easier to construct a neural network with these assumptions, compared to
the case when you send a single image to a network (which requires that you have
trained the network with a multitude of images) ? If so, then how?
Could a Convolutional Neural Network be used?
